# I am facing issue while updating the data into table in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, package, relationship, yii2-advanced-app

One of my colleague used below package in yii2 relation. Now while updating data some times i got below errors.

[Package link](https://github.com/la-haute-societe/yii2-save-relations-behavior).

Error :

```
 "name": "Exception",
    "message": "Unable to link models: the link defining the relation does not involve any primary key.",
    "code": 0,
    "type": "yii\\base\\InvalidCallException",
    "file": "/app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php",
    "line": 1352,
    "stack-trace": [
        "#0 /app/vendor/la-haute-societe/yii2-save-relations-behavior/src/SaveRelationsBehavior.php(558): yii\\db\\BaseActiveRecord->link('metafields', Object(shopify\\models\\VariantMetafield), Array)",
        "#1 /app/vendor/la-haute-societe/yii2-save-relations-behavior/src/SaveRelationsBehavior.php(512): lhs\\Yii2SaveRelationsBehavior\\SaveRelationsBehavior->_afterSaveHasManyRelation('metafields')",
```

My model code :

```
    public function behaviors(){
        
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        
        $behaviors[] = [
            'class' => SaveRelationsBehavior::className(),
            'relationKeyName' => SaveRelationsBehavior::RELATION_KEY_RELATION_NAME,
            'relations' => [
                'images',
                'options',
                'variants', 
                'metafields',  
                'tags',
                'vendors',
                'productTypes' 
            ]
        ]; 
        return $behaviors;
    }

public function getMetafields(){
            
            $productMetafieldClass  = Yii::$app->factory->getClassByResource(Factory::PRODUCT_METAFIELD);
            
            return $this->hasMany($productMetafieldClass, [
                'owner_id'          => 'id',
                'consumer_id'       => 'consumer_id'
            ]);
        }
```

Can anyone help me how to fix above issue.
Thanks.

### Table Structures :

Variants table

```
CREATE TABLE `variants` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'unique identifier of Shopify Shop',
  `product_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unique identifier of shop',
  `consumer_id` int(30) NOT NULL COMMENT 'unique identifier of shop',
  `option1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `option2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `option3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `compare_at_price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `fulfillment_service` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `grams` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unique identifier of shop',
  `inventory_item_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unique identifier of shop',
  `inventory_management` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `inventory_policy` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `inventory_quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `taxable` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tax_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight_unit` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The date and time (ISO 8601) when the customer was updated.',
  `updated_at` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The date and time (ISO 8601) when the customer was updated.',
  `update_hash` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `condition` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `feed_image_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index__variants-consumer_id` (`id`,`consumer_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index__variants-product_id` (`id`,`product_id`,`consumer_id`),
  KEY `fk__variants__consumers-id` (`consumer_id`),
  KEY `fk__variants-product_id__product-id` (`product_id`,`consumer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__variants-product_id__product-id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`, `consumer_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`, `consumer_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk__variants__consumers-id` FOREIGN KEY (`consumer_id`) REFERENCES `consumers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Metafields table

```
CREATE TABLE `metafields` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'unique identifier of Shopify Shop',
  `owner_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unique identifier of shop',
  `owner_resource` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `namespace` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value_type` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The date and time (ISO 8601) when the customer was updated.',
  `updated_at` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The date and time (ISO 8601) when the customer was updated.',
  `consumer_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unique identifier of shop',
  `update_hash` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index__product_metafields-consumer_id` (`id`,`consumer_id`),
  KEY `fk__product_metafields__consumers-id` (`consumer_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk__product_metafields__consumers-id` FOREIGN KEY (`consumer_id`) REFERENCES `consumers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 1):

The `link()` method of `yii\db\ActiveRecord` is expecting the relation to use primary key.
By default the frameworks finds the primary key from db schema but your tables doesn't have any primary keys.

You can try to override [`primaryKey()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#primaryKey()-detail) method in your model to make framework use columns with unique index as primary key instead of looking for them in db schema.

In your model class

```php
public static function primaryKey()
{
    return ['id', 'consumer_id'];
}
```